# Transparent Activity Mixed Screen

Tags: android, android-activity

My project has an activity like popup screen. Styles look like this

```
<style name="ContentPopupTheme" parent="Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/PopupMenu.MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name ="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

There is a problem when I open the activity:

https://ibb.co/F6v8pDh

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: shared gif please check again